# Can "people with confusion" refer to people that are confused?

Tags: prepositions, translation

I need to refer to a specific group of people that **are feeling confused** like me.

According to my research, "with confusion" is used when dealing with confusion as an illness but not a feeling or state. I wonder what is the correct preposition to use before confusion to indicate it as a feeling/state, or if, by any chance, **with** is the correct one?

> But then the **people with confusion** such as me suddenly approached us.

---

*I would like to preserve (if possible) the order and type of the words used in the sentence which is one of a translated poem.*

Comment: Not people with confusion. Confused people such as myself suddenly etc. But you might find a better word.

Comment: I would go with what you suggested if there is no way to form my intended meaning with the noun "confusion".

Comment: maybe, "But then people, confused like me, suddenly approached us." If it's everyone around, use "the people"

Comment: But then people, *who were just as confused as I was*, suddenly approached me.

Comment: @mkennedy _ Can I use **the people** if they were a specific, known group of people to the speaker? Because you mentioned that they should be around him when they are, in fact, not.

Comment: @AIQ _ Because it is a translation, I wouldn't change it too much (if not at all), but your version is the best so far.